# Regex Multiple Negative Lookahead

Tags: java, regex

Here is my regex pattern: `[Ss]ection\s\d+(?![a-zA-z])(?!</ref>)`

For example, it should match: `section 5` or `section 50`

For example, it should **not** match: `section 5A` or `section 5</ref>` or `section 5A</ref>` or `section 50A`

Problem is that in reality it matches them wrong: http://regexr.com?33ien

Not sure what's wrong with the pattern though...

Comment: Is `[Ss]ection\s\d++(?![a-zA-z])(?!</ref>)` solving your problem?

Comment: @Pshemo: what does `\d++` do?

Comment: @jlordo.. `\d++` is a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Comment: @Pshemo: Can you post that comment as an answer please

Comment: _Facepalm_... I've posted this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) quite often myself. Makes sense, I've never had a use case for it, though.

Comment: @Pshemo. You should post your answer. It's better than the current ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe try `[Ss]ection\s\d++(?![a-zA-z])(?!</ref>)`. ++ is [possessive quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html). This quantifier is similar to greedy quantifier except it blocks fragment of string that it matched from being used by later part of regex.

Example

```
System.out.println("ababab".matches("(ab)++ab")); 
// prints false since last "ab" is possessed by (ab)++
```

Answer (score 2):

The matches are not wrong : in your regex you want "section " followed by one or more digits not followed by some text or ""

Thats true for `section 50A` :

`section 5` is followed by `0A` and thats not in your negative lookahead.

You can do something like :

```
[Ss]ection\s\d+(?![a-zA-Z0-9])(?!</ref>)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
[Ss]ection\s\d+(?!\d)(?![a-zA-z])(?!</ref>)
```

I've explained a problem with our thinking about regexp lookaheads at [Strangeness with negative lookahead assertion in Java regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367854/strangeness-with-negative-lookahead-assertion-in-java-regular-expression/14368133#14368133), it's applicable here as well.

The situation here is slightly different: negative lookahead does match when we don't want it to, because the matcher *is inclined to accept shorter match for the pre-lookahead part if it helps matching expression as a whole*. That's why it's important to have an idea of input boundary if you use lookahead: be it a word boundary, an anchor `$`, or some assertion about the following text (*not looking at a digit* in my proposed solution).